# WPF Binding to IDataErrorInfo.Error property design time issue

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, idataerrorinfo

I want to Bind a TextBox.Text to my object IDataErrorInfo.Error property that return summary of errors. My object is DataContext.
Now i've a textbox like that:

```
<TextBox xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=System" Text="{Binding Path=(sys:IDataErrorInfo.Error), Mode=OneWay}" />
```

and all works fine at runtime but at design time Visual Studio 2010 show an error: InvalidOperationException was thrown on "Binding": Object 'null' cannot be used as an accessor parameter for a PropertyPath. An accessor must be DependencyProperty, PropertyInfo, or PropertyDescriptor.
Now with this error (in yellow bar) i can not use property toolbox to edit my windows.
Anyone can help me solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this 

`Text="{Binding Path=Error, Mode=OneWay}"`

Comment: I implement interface implicitly for different reasons and doesn't work.